# Getting timezone from date and place

Tags: ios, xcode, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my app I have a date and place value which I would like to add the appropriate timezone.

What I have now:

`14 Feb 2014 - 11:45 from Munich` or `14 Feb 2014 - 15:05 to New York`

I would like to change it to:

`14 Feb 2014 - 11:45 AM GMT+1 from Munich` or `14 Feb 2014 - 3:05 PM EST to New York`

Is there any way I can find out the timezone for the date and place?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you determining the names for the places?  Is it just free-form input from a user?

Comment: They are fixed within the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said the locations are fixed in your app, you should simply assign each of your locations to an actual [IANA time zone](http://iana.org/time-zones) identifier to start with.

For example, Munich would be covered by the `Europe/Berlin` time zone, and New York is (of course) in `America/New_York`.  You can review the list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Now that you know the time zone for the location, you can easily determine the offset for the local time, or get an abbreviation.  You can use the `NSTimeZone` class for that.  [The reference is here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you get an abbreviation, make sure you understand that time zone abbreviations are *for display only*.  You can show them to a user, but there is too much ambiguity to correlate an abbreviation like EST or CST back to a particular time zone.

Comment: I almost thought something like that. Thank you very much for the clarification.